# Number of tokens in code

Tags: c, token, lexical-analysis, compiler-construction

```
 void main()
 {
    i/* nt */a=10;
    return;
 }
```

Number of tokens in above code:?

I have calculated it as 13 by removing comment and not considering white space

Does we consider 'i' and 'a' as single token after removing comment?
Thanks lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's two tokens. A comment is replaced with a single space, so after the comment is removed it's equivalent to:

```
i a=10;
```

The space separates tokens.

From [Wikipedia article on the C Preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor)

> 3. Tokenization: The preprocessor breaks the result into preprocessing tokens and whitespace. It replaces comments with whitespace.

Comment: 1 void
2 main
3 (
4 )
5 {
6 i
7 a
8 =
9 10
10 ;
11 return
12 ;
13 } why it is wrong?

Comment: I mean How you got 10 ?can you please explain more :)

Comment: I didn't get 10, that's just part of the statement `i/* nt */a=10;`

Comment: ok i got it and can you please provide more reference for it.

Comment: I added a reference from Wikipedia